# How to show JSON data on html table according to dynamic data using jquery?

Tags: jquery, vb.net, jquery-ui, c#-4.0, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to show JSON data in a HTML table, but I'm not sure how. I'm trying to use jQuery.

My data looks like this:

```
{
    "error": "",
    "response_code": 200,
    "position": "Train Arrived at Barauni Jn. (BJU) at 05:45 PM",
    "train_number": "12554",
    "total": 21,
    "route": [
        {
            "status": "No Delay",
            "actdep": "07:50 PM",
            "station": "New Delhi (NDLS)",
            "actarr": "12:00 AM",
            "no": 1,
            "scharr": "Source",
            "schdep": "07:50 PM"
        }, {
            "status": "4 Minutes Before",
            "actdep": "08:28 PM",
            "station": "Ghaziabad (GZB)",
            "actarr": "08:26 PM",
            "no": 2,
            "scharr": "08:30 PM",
            "schdep": "08:32 PM"
        }, 
        //...
        {
            "status": "30 Minutes Late",
            "actdep": "N/A",
            "station": "Barauni Jn (BJU)",
            "actarr": "05:45 PM",
            "no": 21,
            "scharr": "05:15 PM",
            "schdep": "Destination"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: you should format your question first, then post what have you tried so far??

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. Added some notes walking you through what it is doing. I made the assumption that you are trying to loop through the collection routes.

**HTML:**

```
<table id="routes" class="table">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

**jQuery:**

```
function dataToTable($table, obj, collectionName) {

    //Load the properties as headings.
    $thead = $table.find('thead');
    $tr = $('<tr />');
    //get property names and add a th for each property
    for (property in obj[collectionName][0]) {
        $th = $('<th />');
        $th.html(property);
        $tr.append($th);
    }
    //append header row to thead
    $thead.append($tr);

    //load the data from the routes to the tbody.
    $tbody = $table.find('tbody');

    $.each(obj[collectionName], function () {
        //create row per record
        $tr = $('<tr />');
        //dynamically get values by property name and load to a td
        for (property in this) {
            $td = $('<td />');
            $td.html(this[property]);
            $tr.append($td);
        }
        //append row to tbody
        $tbody.append($tr);
    });

}

//function run example
dataToTable($('#routes'),data,'route')
```

DEMO:

http://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/6ozt7n66/

Comment: I think I am unable to add your code in my side as below process that is not working...

Comment: try passing data.d instead of data something like... dataToTable($('#routes'), data.d, 'route') if that doesn't work add a line console.log(data) and edit your question with the results from the console.